No se muestran mensaje al seleccionar checkbox en javascript
Quiero que al seleccionarlos se me muestre una alerta o un mensaje que me diga cuantos países seleccioné, y simplemente no me funciona. He intentado cambiar el navegador, desactivar extensiones, reiniciar y demás pero nada parece hacerlo funcionar.
Este es el código que tengo:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Checkbox</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h4>Pais</h4>
        <form action="#">
            <label for="">
                <input type="checkbox" id="check1" name="check" value="Usa">Usa
            </label>
            <label for="">
                <input type="checkbox" id="check2" name="check" value="Colombia">Colombia
            </label>
            <label for="">
                <input type="checkbox" id="check3" name="check" value="Panama">Panama
            </label>
            <label for="">
                <input type="checkbox" id="check4" name="check" value="Costa">Costa rica
            </label>
            <label for="">
                <input type="checkbox" id="check5" name="check" value="Chile">Chile<br>
            </label>
            <input type="button" value="Seleccionar" onclick="select()">
        </form>

    <script>
        function select() {
            let cantidad = 0;
            if(document.getElementById('check1').checked){
                cantidad++;
            }
            if(document.getElementById('check2').checked){
                cantidad++;
            }
            if(document.getElementById('check3').checked){
                cantidad++;
            }
            if(document.getElementById('check4').checked){
                cantidad++;
            }
            if(document.getElementById('check5').checked){
                cantidad++;
            }
            alert(cantidad);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>




Para este caso particular, bastaría con reemplazar el <input type="button"> por el elemento HTML <button>. Aún así, no está demás recordar que se desaconseja usar manejadores de eventos inline.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Checkbox</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h4>Pais</h4>
        <form action="#">
            <label for="">
                <input type="checkbox" id="check1" name="check" value="Usa">Usa
            </label>
            <label for="">
                <input type="checkbox" id="check2" name="check" value="Colombia">Colombia
            </label>
            <label for="">
                <input type="checkbox" id="check3" name="check" value="Panama">Panama
            </label>
            <label for="">
                <input type="checkbox" id="check4" name="check" value="Costa">Costa rica
            </label>
            <label for="">
                <input type="checkbox" id="check5" name="check" value="Chile">Chile<br>
            </label>
            <button onclick="select()">Seleccionar</button>
        </form>

    <script>
        function select() {
            let cantidad = 0;
            if(document.getElementById('check1').checked){
                cantidad++;
            }
            if(document.getElementById('check2').checked){
                cantidad++;
            }
            if(document.getElementById('check3').checked){
                cantidad++;
            }
            if(document.getElementById('check4').checked){
                cantidad++;
            }
            if(document.getElementById('check5').checked){
                cantidad++;
            }
            alert(cantidad);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>




En cuanto a la pregunta del select(), tal como mencionó Excorpion, justamente el nombre de la función coincide con una función nativa. La especificación en el estándar HTML dice lo siguiente (traducción y énfasis míos):

El método select(), al ser invocado, debe seguir los siguientes pasos:
1. Si el elemento es un elemento input, y select() no se aplica a este elemento o el control correspondiente no tiene texto seleccionable, retornar. (...)

En síntesis: básicamente se ignora la llamada al método.

Has sugerido un cambio de input, por el button, pero no has dicho porque es este cambio, lo cuál me ha dejado confuso. Yo veo solamente que el OP ha chocado con la función nativa de javascript, al renombrar la función select(), por otra que no sea nativa, no se produce el problema.

Ahora sí @Excorpion (Y)

MDN es la referencia más cercana a lo oficial con que contamos, pero MDN no es solo un sitio de referencias, tiene guías, blog y más. El enlace que comenta que los eventos inline son una mala práctica pertenece a la sección de guías (no a la de referencias) cuya autoría pertenece contribuciones de usuarios anónimos, es decir tiene la misma valides que un blog escrito por cualquiera, las razones que se esgrimen son de lo más cuestionables y la principal razón que podría haber para no usarlo la omiten (que es el alcance global requerido para que funcione).

Por otro lado, en la sección de referencia https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element#events habla que hay 2 formas de conectar eventos y no desaconseja ninguna. Mi intención no es debatir del tema, si no que mostrar a futuros lectores que la posición planteada no es oficial y que básicamente es algo opinable

Por eso, como ya he mencionado en varias ocasiones: se desaconseja.

Muchas gracias a todos por sus respuestas, fueron de gran ayuda para solucionar el problema, además aprendí varias cosas nuevas.

Un input cuenta nativamente con una función llama select, entonces cuando tu haces:
<input type="button" value="Seleccionar" onclick="select()">

Se está llamando a esa función nativa y no a la tuya. La solución:

Es utilizar un <button type="button">
O sencillamente utilizar otro nombre en la función



function otronombre() {
  select();
}

function select() {
  let cantidad = 0;
  if (document.getElementById('check1').checked) {
    cantidad++;
  }
  if (document.getElementById('check2').checked) {
    cantidad++;
  }
  if (document.getElementById('check3').checked) {
    cantidad++;
  }
  if (document.getElementById('check4').checked) {
    cantidad++;
  }
  if (document.getElementById('check5').checked) {
    cantidad++;
  }
  alert(cantidad);
}


/* otro modo de hacerlo
function select() {

  let checked = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]')).filter(a=>a.checked);
  alert(checked.length);
}
*/
<h4>Pais</h4>
<form action="#">
  <label for="">
     <input type="checkbox" id="check1" name="check" value="Usa">Usa
  </label>
  <label for="">
     <input type="checkbox" id="check2" name="check" value="Colombia">Colombia
  </label>
  <label for="">
     <input type="checkbox" id="check3" name="check" value="Panama">Panama
  </label>
  <label for="">
     <input type="checkbox" id="check4" name="check" value="Costa">Costa rica
  </label>
  <label for="">
     <input type="checkbox" id="check5" name="check" value="Chile">Chile<br>
  </label>

  <input type="button" value="Seleccionar" onclick="otronombre()">
  <button type="button" onclick="select()">Seleccionar button</button>
</form>




Has sugerido un cambio de input, por el button, pero no has dicho porque es este cambio, lo cuál me ha dejado confuso. Yo veo solamente que el OP ha chocado con la función nativa de javascript, como has mencionado antes. Falta el contexto del botón, ya que probando probando, no hay diferencias.

@Excorpion Es el input el que tiene la función select, que se utiliza mayormente para cuando es del tipo text. En otras palabras, no es una función global es del input y solo de él. Por tanto, al cambiarlo por un <button> soluciona el problema ya que este último no cuenta con esa función
